# How do I change my nav menu bar to say 'Logout' when logged in

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a small project to get a basic website done and I can't figure out how in php I get my menu navbar to change to Logout as soon as the user has successfully signed in.

I've pasted the navbar code and all the code I think which may be relevant. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Quite new to php, you may need to see all the code below so apologise if not much help. The PHP code was used from a YouTube tutorial....

NavBar Menu Code

iStudy University

```
    <section class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myTogglerNav">
    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="index.php"><i class="fas fa-home"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Home</span></i></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="about.html"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; About</span></i></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="contact.html"><i class="fas fa-envelope"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Contact Us</span></i></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="signup.php"><i class="fas fa-check-square"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Sign Up</span></i></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="login.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Login</span></i></a>
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Some PHP which is applied:

```
          <?php
        if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
          echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
          </form>';
        }
        else if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
          echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
          </form>';
        }
    ?>
```

The signup form code:

```
<form class="form-signup" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
        <?php
        // Here we check if the user already tried submitting data.

        // We check username.
        if (!empty($_GET["uid"])) {
          echo '<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username" value="'.$_GET["uid"].'">';
        }
        else {
          echo '<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">';
        }

        // We check e-mail.
        if (!empty($_GET["mail"])) {
          echo '<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email" value="'.$_GET["mail"].'">';
        }
        else {
          echo '<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email">';
        }
        ?>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password">
        <button type="submit" name="signup-submit">Signup</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: Do an `if` `else` statement on your `<a>` tag based on `$_SESSION['id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same that's been done for your form on the `<a>` tag in your navigation.

```
<section class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myTogglerNav">
<div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="index.php"><i class="fas fa-home"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Home</span></i></a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="about.html"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; About</span></i></a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="contact.html"><i class="fas fa-envelope"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Contact Us</span></i></a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="signup.php"><i class="fas fa-check-square"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Sign Up</span></i></a>
     <?php  
          if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            echo "<a class='nav-item nav-link px-3' href='login.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-in-alt'><span class='nav-text'>&nbsp; Login</span></i></a>";
          } else {
            echo "<a class='nav-item nav-link px-3' href='logout.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-out-alt'><span class='nav-text'>&nbsp; Logout</span></i></a>";
          }
      ?>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks @Raylene, I've tried to paste this code in, however 'LOGIN' in the menu navbar is still not altering to LOGOUT once I've successfully logged in.Is it the fact I have a page called 'login.inc.php' and 'logout.inc.php' which I need to include somewhere? It was an <action> which was code taken from the YouTube video (the logout essentially just destroys session etc) and the login.inc.php starts the sessions and does all the checking. That code in the middle snippet of this question. It's always difficult following a YouTube tutorial and then merging your code!

Comment: Does the php snippet in your above code work as expected for the form?

Comment: Hi Raylene, your code was correct so I marked this as answered however I'm sure there's a mistake elsewhere in my code which is automatically saying logout....before even logging in. So I've raised another Question on here specifically for that :)